# Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I was trying to port a huge application to android studio, But I stuck with the following bug

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:calendar2014:assembleDebug]Error:(40, 9) Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:40:9
is also present at Calendar20155:wheel:unspecified:11:18 value=(Android Wheel Widget)
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:33:5 to override
```

`:calendar2014:processDebugManifest FAILED`

I tried to add     `xmlns:tools="....."` to my manifest file. And it shows inactive. Please do share the solution if you have any.

Comment: please share `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: just added a screenshot of my manifest file

Comment: Geethu, why not showing full AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 2):

You must delete that attribute on AndroidManifest of android folder:

1. Go to

/your_direction/AndroidStudioProjects/my_flutter_app/android/app/src/main/**AndroidManifest**

2. And Delete

android:label="your_app_name"

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion is given in logcat itself. Try

```
tools:replace="android:label
```

to application tag in manifest

Comment: Sorry I didn't read that part. Let me see if there exists another solution. Can u post your grade and manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

Late but my solution to this error was to make the two values consistent. So change "Android Wheel Widget" to "@string/app_name"

Comment: Was getting this error in a new .NET Maui project implementing in Android. Thanks!